# Slick Slider caching the first image

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider that gets reinitialized with new images and when I go to slide from the last image to the first image it shows the image from the old set of images, but does not do that for all the other images. It does it every time you go from the last to first image. Is there a way to disable this or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant HTML, jQuery and CSS.

Comment: @Yass Unfortunately, no. But it is a `div` with `img` tags where the `img` tags get a new source and get redrawn. Since slick is already initialized, it doesn't re-run (and slick throws an error `Cannot read property 'add' of null` if you do).

Comment: Since it is redrawing the `img` tags, but since it adds a duplicate of the first image, that one is not being redrawn with the new source.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update the clones with the new urls.

```
let clones = document.getElementById(<your id>).querySelectorAll('img.slick-cloned');

clones[0].setAttribute('src', <your url>);

clones[1].setAttribute('src', <your url>);
```